# How to specify the same transition speed for all slides, regardless of their width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

How to specify the same transition speed for all slides, regardless of their width? Now the transition speed depends on the width of the slide - the wider the slide, the faster the transition occurs.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XoyZNr

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const sl = new Swiper(slider, {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  loop: true,
  speed: 5000,
  autoplay: {
    enabled: true,
    delay: 1,
  },
});
```

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.slider__item {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/css/swiper.min.css" />
<div class="slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#looooooo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#hellohellohellohellohello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#Lorem, ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#boo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#go</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems they calculate on the bases of width, you might need to deep dive into plugin

Comment: @keks I see that the code in stackoverflow has constant widths for all slides irrespective of text, resulting in the same speeds for all slides. But in codepen the widths are different, causing different speeds

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be dependent on the width of the elements themselves and I was not able to find a way to perform calculations to the width when passing the `speed` parameter.

I'd like to suggest a workaround for this issue till we find an answer, you can either set a constant width by removing `width: auto` or allow swiper to do it for you by setting the `slidesPerView` attribute and make the text look pretty by centering it. I think a good value is the `floor(max width of current screen form factor / width of the largest slide)` so if your largest slide is `120px` in width and the target screen is `240px`, you can fit 2 slides in at a time.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const sl = new Swiper(slider, {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  loop: true,
  speed: 5000,
  slidesPerView: '2',
  autoplay: {
    enabled: true,
    delay: 1,
  },
});
```

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.slider__item {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/css/swiper.min.css" />
<div class="slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#looooooo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#hellohellohellohellohello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#Lorem, ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#boo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider__item">#go</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```