# Swiperjs slows in the center

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, swiper.js

I am using Swiperjs as I am looking for an infinite looping swiper that never stops in the middle however I have tried many settings and cant seem to get it to work where it is the same speed and no jumping and no slowing down as it gets to the center.

Below is the best I have got it where it does not jump but it slows down as it gets into the center.

```
const params = {
      loop: true,
       speed: 5000,
       freeMode: true,
       freeModeFluid:true,
       resistance: false,
       simulateTouch: false,
       waitForTransition: false,
       centeredSlides: false,
       freeModeMomentum: false,
       freeModeMinimumVelocity: 0,
       freeModeMomentumBounceRatio: 0,
       freeModeMomentumBounce: false,
       normalizeSlideIndex: false,

      autoplay: {
          delay: 1,
          disableOnInteraction: true,
        }

  }
```

Comment: Anyone got any ideas ?

Comment: No way to understand your issue. What do you mean "slow"?... Also, add code snippet. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: By slow I mean that when you get to the center it slows down so. Its fast going in from right and as it gets to the center it slows down and then after pauses for a micro second and then goes off again.

Comment: Already got a code snippet above.

Comment: I guess everyone as clueless as me.

Comment: Try this CSS: .swiper-wrapper { transition-timing-function: linear;}. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159086/how-to-specify-the-same-transition-speed-for-all-slides-regardless-of-their-wid